# Проблема при подключении style.css

Tags: css, scss

Проблема появилась вчера, после установки live_sass. Код не компилировался в css. Плагин ставил/удалял несколько раз, настройки плагина правильные. Сейчас в папке css при создании файла style.css перед ним появляется "#" [image: # style.css]

и style.css не подключается. Пробовал и на портативной версии, без плагинов - тоже самое. Подскажите, где копать?
Путь такой:

Comment: Не подключается вероятно потому что путь к файлу в разметке не указан, или указан неправильный (не факт, но самая распространенная ошибка из возможных); Решетка - это иконка такая у файлов стилей в редакторе, пугаться ее не нужно; Копать - вроде рано еще (хотя хз, я без дачи), подожди пока корнеплоды созреют.

Comment: Если директория `css/` расположена на одном уровне вложенности с html-файликом, то подключение стилей в разметке предполагается вида `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">`.

Comment: киньте html разметку. возможно вы не правильно подключаете файл css